# Laptop slowness when connected with a docking station

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, hdmi

My setup:

An Asus laptop running Win 8.1 Enterprise with 16 GB RAM, Intel Core i7, nVidia Geforce GTX850 DDR3 4GB RAM,  HDD 1TB + SSD 256GB.

This configuration is running smooth and I don't have any problems with the laptop. But at work I plug it in this [docking stations/hub](http://www.evomag.ro/COMPONENTE-PC-Hub-USB/PNI-Hub-USB-Multifunctional-PNI-USB-3.0-DVI-Retea-HDMI-112210.html). In the hub I plug:

- a keyboard
- a LCD display through DVI
- a LCD display through VGA=>HDMI adapter
- LAN
- headset

It ran pretty well for about three months. But lately I get these episodes when the OS gets very slow. Most of the times I restart the explorer task and it seems to work ok after. But these episodes are happening more often and I really don't know how to debug it. 
I tried to exclude applications, Skype being the primary suspect, but I didn't get any results.

Where should I start looking?

Comment: Do these occur only when you're using the docking station with all peripherals attached to it? Did you make any changes to your computer recently, i.e. installed new hardware/software?

Comment: Yes, only when using the docking station. But as I said, it worked well before. I didn't change the hardware setup and I don't remember installing something new & important. But I keep all my updates up to date.

Comment: capture and share a xperf trace of the slowness: http://pastebin.com/9R3Ehbs3 .Here I capture some shell perf data from the Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

On the software side, you can install a clean OS on an external hard drive just to see if the issue was caused by any software you are using.

On the hardware side, check if your laptop is overheating when this is happening. It could be your CPU is thermal throttling.

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely you're overloading the device. Like you've stated, the problem only occurs when you're using the docking station. This leads me to believe that you're probably using the device beyond its capabilities.

I would contact the manufacturer for further support. Tell them that you're only having these problems when you're connected to the device. They'll probably ask you to re-install drivers (if any).

What I would try is minimize the amount of peripherals you plug into it. Try to find a sweet spot to prevent it from overloading. If you're still experiencing problems, maybe it's time to consider returning the device and asking for a refund.

Comment: This is one of the causes that I thought of. I tried removing a display but the problem still existed. I will probably need to remove everything and start testing from there. Or else, change the hub. But I really hoped someone will give me a solution. 

If I will go down this route I will mark your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is stupid: the problem was my usb keyboard all along.

Thanks for the answers. I won't mark this as bring the right answer but I wanted to write it here for those with the same problem: also check your keyboard.